# Profile analysis in time series with multiple paired groups

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, stata

I have two different sources of data on popularity of volunteering in 100 countries for each of 5 years. So I have 2*100*5 data points. I want to know if the different sources say the same thing at all or if they are completely unrelated.

The 5-year trends are almost certainly not linear.

I could do 100 separate profile analyses but a) tiny sample sizes and b)  I would miss what is shared between all of them - 1) a possible level 1 effect (volunteering is changing over the 5 years across all countries and both sources) and 2) also possible level 2 effects (the two sources differ from one another systematically across all countries; the 100 country trends differ from one another systematically across both sources). What I am really interested in is, *having removed* those effects, are the profiles still similar between sources (even if they are quite different between countries)?

I guess I can consider country to be a random effect and source to be a fixed effect ... but not sure how to do a mixed-effects model in this case.

Is there a single test I can do which will combine them all into one test?

Comment: I think a structural equation model framework may offer you sufficient flexibility to address your question. Multilevel models are possible and depending on how you set up the model you can test relevant paths for your two assessments for equivalence. Should you desire you can also test your model while specifying a functional form for change over time.

Comment: @MattBarstead You mean treating the 5 time-points as 5 separate variables with arrows 1->2, 2->3 etc, and also from country, source and country*source to each time point? A kind of path diagram with no latent variables, like this: http://theorymaker.info/?permalink=SEM-time

Comment: There are actually a range of options to consider based on the specific question you want to address in SEM. One option is to ignore change over time and treat each of your annual measures as an indicator of a latent variable representing "volunteerism" over a 5-span in each country. Within this approach you could test whether the loadings for year 1 measure 1 are equivalent to year 1 measure 2 (and the same goes for years 2, 3, 4, and 5).

Comment: Another option is to model change over time explicitly, particularly if you have hypotheses about the ways in which volunteerism may have fluctuated on average over the 5-year span you have targeted. Just thinking off the cuff, something like a parallel growth process might be one route to go. Within an SEM framework you would specify an intercept and a slope (or slopes if you believe that change is non-linear), and you could compare the slopes and intercepts between the two measures to see if their change functions are similar.